# Tridion Reference Implementation - Experience Manager button does not show

Tags: experience-manager, dxa

I have just installed the Tridion Reference Implementation, which went like a breeze. Installed the TRS site as a Staging site, and configured the Publication Target for inline editing.

However when I pull up the site, the SDL Tridion button to open Experience Manager does not show up. Also when I view source I don't see the XPM comments in the markup.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If there is no XPM markup at all, it is very likely that the example website is thinking that you are not on a Staging website. When publishing the Settings, there is a flag published, so the Website can distinguish when it is running on staging and generate the XPM markup.

To generate this flag the TBB's rely on the **publication target name**. This means that the publication target name needs to contain the text: **"staging"** , for XPM to be enabled on that publication target. You can find this flag serialized on the filesystem in: **YourApplicationPath\BinaryData\system\config\_all.json**

**Probably renaming your Publication Target to something containing staging and republishing "Publish Settings" will solve the issue**

Make sure to access **yourwebsitedomain/admin/refresh** to clear the cache and to restart your appool

Another reason for the button not appearing is usually because the cms url is not properly configured on the **Environment Configuration component**, located in: **\100 Master\Building Blocks\Settings\Core\Admin\Environment Configuration**. You need to change this and publish the "Publish Settings" Page

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the extra edit! That was exactly it; had to include the word "staging" in the Publication Target title.

This should be configurable since some prefer "preview" as target name (like me)

Comment: Would Publication Metadata or maybe AppData be a better place for such a configuration? And either way, would a simple string be enough, or would it be better as a selection (something like with @BartKoopman's Item Selector extension).

Comment: @AlvinReyes I'm adding it to the list for future improvements, it would be nice if we would just follow the XPM settings (if the target is enabled for inline editing), but those are going to changed in the next release.

Comment: Thanks, Bart! Any preference on where we should discuss/request TRI features (aside from TRex comments)? :-)

Comment: @AlvinReyes yes, please add any issues/enhacements to https://github.com/bkoopman/tri/issues

Comment: Ok, I didn't the issue yet, so to practice (and start a good habit) I added: https://github.com/bkoopman/tri/issues/10.